# Age Verification - Close Dialog Window

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, verification, gate

Using Nation Builder as a platform for a client's site and need to create an age gate. I would have the age verification on a separate page but apparently it won't work with this platform, so I'm using a Jquery dialog to show on top of the home page. The code I got to verify age works, but need to tweak it in order to close the widget UI instead of a url redirect.

I'm no programming expert so any help and dumming it down would be appreciated. Here's a link. http://patricialourenco.com/test.html
Cheers!

```
var ageCheck = {

  //Set the minimum age and where to redirect to
  minimumAge : 13,
  userIsOldEnoughPage : "http://www.bullyproject.com",
  userNotOldEnoughPage : " http://www.pacerkidsagainstbullying.org/#/home",


  //Leave this stuff alone please :)

  start: function() {
    this.setUsersBirthday();
    if (this.userIsOverMinimumAge()) {
      this.setCookie("usersBirthday",this.usersBirthday,30);
      window.location = this.userIsOldEnoughPage; 
    } else{
      this.notMinimumAge();
    };
  }, 

  usersBirthday : new Date(),

  setTheMonth : function() {
    var selectedMonth = document.getElementById("month").value;
    if (selectedMonth === "1") {
      this.setDaysForMonth(29);
    } 
    else if (selectedMonth === "3" ||
             selectedMonth === "5" || 
             selectedMonth === "8" ||
             selectedMonth === "10") {
      this.setDaysForMonth(30);
    }
    else {
      this.setDaysForMonth(31);
    };
  },

  setDaysForMonth : function(x) {
    var daySelectTag = document.getElementsByName('day')[0];
    daySelectTag.options.length = 0;
      for(var i=1; i <= x; i++) {
      daySelectTag.options.add(new Option(i, i));
    }
  },

  setUsersBirthday: function() {
    var usersMonth = document.getElementById("month").value;
    var usersDay = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var usersYear = document.getElementById("year").value;
    this.usersBirthday.setMonth(usersMonth);
    this.usersBirthday.setDate(usersDay);
    this.usersBirthday.setFullYear(usersYear);
  },

  setMinimumAge: function() {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - this.minimumAge);
    return today;
  },

  notMinimumAge : function() {
    window.location = this.userNotOldEnoughPage
  },

  userIsOverMinimumAge: function () {
    if (this.usersBirthday < this.setMinimumAge()) {
      return true;
    }
  },

  setCookie: function (c_name,value,exMinutes) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setMinutes(exdate.getMinutes() + exMinutes);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exMinutes==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
  },

  getCookie: function (c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
      {
        return unescape(x);
      }
    }
  },

  checkCookie:   function () {
    var usersBirthday=this.getCookie("usersBirthday");
    if (usersBirthday==null || usersBirthday=="") {
      window.location = "ageCheckTester.html";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you make your dialog box with the attribute "modal: true", the user has to close the dialog in order to go to the site.  If you want to make them enter their age, then this will the correct solution and handle the possibilities within the dialog itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the .close method - here's how you'd use it, after the user has pushed the button to submit their age:

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog('close'); //hides modal, shows content behind
```

More documentation on jQuery UI dialogs:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

---

EDIT: Here's how you could update your start() method:

```
 start: function() {
   this.setUsersBirthday();
   if (this.userIsOverMinimumAge()) {
     this.setCookie("usersBirthday",this.usersBirthday,30);
     $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
   } else{
     this.notMinimumAge();
   };
 },
```

And a JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/donmccurdy/czERa/

---

EDIT #2 - (Responding to OP's question about checking the cookie on every page)

You had a few bugs in the code that checks the cookie. I've updated the JSFiddle, and here's a quick version of what was wrong:

1) Instead of the code you currently have that always shows the dialog, check the cookie first. Like this:

```
$(function() {
    window.ageCheck.checkCookie();
});
```

2) Update checkCookie() method to show the dialog when necessary:

```
checkCookie:   function () {
  var usersBirthday=this.getCookie("usersBirthday");
  if (!usersBirthday) {
     // unknown age - show dialog.
     $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({modal: true});
     return;
  }
  this.usersBirthday = new Date(usersBirthday);
  if (this.userIsOverMinimumAge()) {
     $('#dialog-modal').hide();
     // user is > 13, don't show dialog.
 } else {
    // user is < 13, redirect to another page.
    this.notMinimumAge(); 
 }
}
```

3) You have a bug in your getCookie method, as you were returning "usersBirthday" instead of the birthday itself. Fixed here:

```
getCookie: function (c_name) {
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
    //split on '=', then check cookie
    x=ARRcookies[i].split('=');
    if (x[0]===c_name){
      return unescape(x[1]);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: He would still have to make it a modal dialog in order to make sure the dialog must be handled first and remove the close button on top of the dialog to avoid somebody just closing it and accessing the page.

Comment: Thanks, yes - In his link the OP is already using `$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({modal: true});` to make the dialog - perhaps he/she already updated it?

Comment: Hmmm, the javascript must be changed still because it's specifying a url instead of closing the modal dialog UI. 

It needs to: 

a) check age
b) if of age: close modal dialog
c) reveal content

Comment: Where you have `window.location = this.userIsOldEnoughPage;` you could just use the code above to close the dialog, I believe. You'll probably still want to redirect like you are if they're < 13.
EDIT: but yes you'll need to move this HTML and JS onto the actual page you're gating off.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thank you for your help, I believe that should do it. Going to test it on the main page. If you don't hear back, then success!

Comment: One last issue,I hope. Because of Nation Builder's platform (similar to WordPress) I have to insert this code in the <head>. Even though I'm allowed access after verification, when navigating to any other page, I'm prompted again with the age gate UI. Wouldn't the cookies disable this from happening once age is verified?

Comment: Yes - you need to check the cookie differently, see my update above. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it resolves the original questions, thanks!

Comment: No change. It's still popping up when I navigate to other pages.

Comment: I can't see the pages you're working on, so you're going to have to debug here. After the line `var usersBirthday=this.getCookie("usersBirthday");` above, call `alert('Actual cookies: ' + document.cookie);` and `alert('Got:' + usersBirthday);` and see what comes up - is the cookie not being set? Or is it not being retrieved by the getCookie method correctly? Remember that you can only retrieve the cookie on the same domain that you set it on.

Comment: As soon as I go to the page, window pops up with
(Actual cookies: __utma=147583400......)

Comment: Right, but do you see your "usersBirthday=..." anywhere in that string? If it's missing, that means the cookie isn't being set correctly. If it's there, that means the cookie isn't being read. I would maybe open a new question on getting/setting cookies, because these comments are getting lengthy and off the topic of the original problem.